# How can I make the AR Core flutter plugin work?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I'm trying to use AR in my flutter app. I'm using the package `arcore_flutter_plugin`.
After adding the plugin, I'm unable to run the app and I get this error (after having disabled the null safety feature) :

```
e: C:\Users\LENOVO THINKPAD\OneDrive\Bureau\Hackathon\ar_test\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (245, 38): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle?): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
e: C:\Users\LENOVO THINKPAD\OneDrive\Bureau\Hackathon\ar_test\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (246, 13): 'onActivityCreated' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':arcore_flutter_plugin:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 57s
```

Can someone help me make it work ?

Comment: Quick question: Why did you disabled null safety? I'm pretty sure tons of libraries make use of it.

Comment: Because the plugin doesn't support null safety feature, so i'm unable to run the app the without desabling null-safety feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error in the arcore_flutter_plugin.

Navigate into the **ArCoreView.kt** file:

> C:\Users\LENOVO
> THINKPAD\OneDrive\Bureau\Hackathon\ar_test\android\src\main
> \kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt

**Remove '?'** from the following line:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

New-line:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same error,
[Error in flutter project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsAs5.png)
which was fixed by changing MotionEvent? ---> MotionEvent[Before changing the code of ArCoreView.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2RCB.png)

[This the image that shows the changes I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHJNR.png)

Comment: It looks like this could be a useful answer, **provided you would remove the images of code and use text instead**. Please update.

Comment: Please review [answer] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1030169)